# How to echo value enter by user in "formatted HTML" in Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have "Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter" with choice type "Formatted HTML" and grove script as below.
Name : FA

```
if{!PATCH.equals("Verify")}
return "<input name='FA' value ='' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
}
```

My pipeline script will be.

```
echo "${params.FA}"
```

it's printing the null value.

Is there any way to use these values in pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return "<input name='value' value ='' class='setting-input' type='text'>"
```

In pipeline print the variable like:

```
print(params.FA)
```

Remember **2 mandatory attributes** for the `<input>`

**name='value'** and **class='setting-input'**